# Degree two map from a complex curve to $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

Good morning! I am trying to find a degree two map $\eta$ from the algebraic curve $\mathcal{C}:y^3+x^3=1$ over $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$ with $\eta(1,0)=\eta(0,1)$. I think that the map
$$\eta:(x,y)\mapsto x+y$$
is the correct one. I am using the degree formula from Miranda's *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces* which state that
$$\deg(\eta)=\sum_{p\in\eta^{-1}(y)}mult_p(\eta)$$
where $y\in\mathbb{P}^1$.
I have chosen $y=1$ (using $\mathbb{P}^1=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$) so that $\eta^{-1}(1)=\{(1,0);(0,1)\}$ so that
$$\deg(\eta)=mult_{(1,0)}(\eta)+mult_{(0,1)}(\eta)$$
Is all this correct? Now I am stucked, how do I calculate multiplicities? I have found something about the relationship with orders but I have no clue now.

Comment: Are you working over $\mathbb{C}$ or a more general field? If the former, "all" you have to do is choose uniformizers $t$ of $\mathbb{P}^1$ at $\eta(0,1)$, $z$ of $\mathcal{C}$ at $(0,1)$, and check which power of $z$ occurs in the decomposition of $t \circ \eta$.

Comment: Yes I'm working over $\mathbb{C}$